# Webpart developed in Sharepoint 2010 and converted to Sharepoint 2007 not working

Tags: ajax, sharepoint

I have created webpart using **Ajax Toolkit**  in SP 2010 and then i have converted it  to Sp 2007 but when i have added that webpart to my Webpage in SP 2007 it is giving me following error

[image]

**NOTE:** I have registered my Ajax Toolkit in my web.config file.

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have Got the solution from following link:

[This link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18778/Microsoft-Office-SharePoint-2007-and-ASP-NET-2-0-A)

and in 9th step of this link i have added following statement in my webparts's header section:

```
using System.Web.Extensions;
```